# how to remove disabled button using PHP, JS when check radio button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

okay, so I create some quiz which showing the question 1 by 1, and each question has prev and next button (except the first which only next button and last question which has prev and submit button). What I want is to prevent user to go to next question without check the radio button (giving the answer)first, so here is my code

I used bootstrap `css` and additional `css`

```
      .container {
        margin-top: 110px;
      }
      .error {
        color: #B94A48;
      }
      .form-horizontal {
        margin-bottom: 0px;
      }
      .hide{display: none;}
```

here is my first question code by PHP assuming the variable i = 1

```
<?php if($i==1){?>
      <div id='question<?php echo $i;?>' class='cont'>
      <?php echo "<h4>".$row['opt1']."</h4>"; ?>
      <input required type="radio" name="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" value="1" id="a1">
      <input required type="radio" name="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" value="2" id="a1">
      <?php echo "<h4>".$row['opt2']."</h4>";?>
      <br>
      <button id='b<?php echo $i;?>' class='next btn btn-success' type='button' disabled="disabled">Next</button></center>
      </div>
<?php }?>
```

lastly I used this javascript to next prev the question

```
     $('.cont').addClass('hide');
     count=$('.questions').length;
     $('#question'+1).removeClass('hide');

     $(document).on('click','.next',function(){
         last=parseInt($(this).attr('id'));     
         nex=last+1;
         $('#question'+last).addClass('hide');
         $('#question'+nex).removeClass('hide');
     });

     $(document).on('click','.previous',function(){
             last=parseInt($(this).attr('id'));     
             pre=last-1;
             $('#question'+last).addClass('hide');

             $('#question'+pre).removeClass('hide');
         });
```

I already tried any suggestion I read like

```
if(document.getElementById('a1').checked) {
      $('.next').removeAttr("disabled");
```

the condition is only if the radio button checked, so if I click previous the next button is already enabled.

I accept any suggestion, is there any other way beside using javascript?

Comment: Start with both previous and next disabled, update them in an onclick handler for the radios.  That assumes you want using prev to force them to click again which is what you seem to be saying:  " so if I click previous the next button is already enabled.".  If you want either (already checked) OR (new click) then you need the radio onClick AND the if checked test

Comment: @Arvind so i must change each radio button id?
DaveS okay, working on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you can add class on radiobutton

```
<input required type="radio" name="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" value="1" id="a1" class="answer">
<input required type="radio" name="<?php echo $row['id'];?>" value="2" id="a1" class="answer">
```

Then you can use this. This code will remove attributes disabled next class, when radiobutton change.

```
$(document).on('change', '.answer', function(){
    $(this).closest('.cont').find('.next').removeAttr("disabled");
});
```